# What is the typical length of a Transport Category Aircraft Maintenance Manual (# of pages)?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

[This](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/maintenance_hf/library/documents/media/roi/tech_pubs_workshop_report_final_9-12.pdf) FAA publication contains the following image:

[image]

The numbers it lists translate to some very long manuals:

- **1998:** 43,071,266 pages/2,532 manuals = 17,010 pages/manual
- **2008:** 184,068,439 pages/5,500 manuals = 33,467 pages/manual

This seems like a lot. 33,000 pages printed out is nearly 11ft on a shelf (that's 3+ meters for those of you not using medieval units)!

Comment: Well, 30 or so chapters with maybe 200-500 pages per in the AMM,  then Component Maintenance Manuals, Wiring Diagram Manuals, Structural Repair Manuals, MMEL, MMEL Document Deviation Guide, Illustrated Parts Catalogs, and some others I can't think of right now.... ats'a lotta pages!  The manuals set for an airliner model will use up a wall of shelf space in a small storage room.